# TinyMCE WYSIWYG Editor changes back to normal textarea when some part of page is refreshed through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tinymce, html-editor

I am using **TinyMCE** WYSIWYG Editor, it is working properly first time, but when i submit its input using ajax then i partially refresh the page, but the problem is after refreshing the page **TinyMCE** converts back into normal textarea in spite of using the following line.

```
tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'}); //in success part of ajax.
```

Javascript

```
function refresh_div(){ 
  $.ajax({
  ......
  success: function(data){
  $('#demo').html(data);
  tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});

 });
}

$(document.body).on('click', '.submit_section' ,function(e){

$.ajax({
  ......
  success: function(data){
  refresh_div();
 });
});
```

Html

```
<textarea>  </textarea>
```

Comment: Vinayakj: I have tried reintializing it but it is not working.

Comment: tried the following but the same issue.- success: function(data){
    
$('#demo').html(data);
        tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor',true,"textarea#expenseComments");
        tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});

Comment: tried but the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Just directly change the contents of editor, below code snippet works fine.

Javascript

```
$(function(){

 tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
  setTimeout(function(){
     $('#tinymcecontainer iframe').contents().find('body').html('New Content');
  },2000)
})
```

Html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<div id="tinymcecontainer">
   <textarea>ABCD</textarea>
<div>
```

In your case,

```
function refresh_div(){ 
  $.ajax({
  ......
  success: function(data){
        $('iframe').contents().find('body').html(data);
 });
}
```